# Print Sales Order Before Place

Tags: magento-enterprise, adminhtml, sales-order, magento-1.14

I'm currently looking into a way to be able to print a sales order (from admin) before being placed with just the product details (Sku, Description, Qty).

The idea is that this could be used as a form of picking list before any payment is made to confirm with customers the items ordered before any payment or processing has been completed.

Any help greatly appreciated.